# Does crosslinking a polymer film increase the stress within the film?

Tags: polymers, soft-matter

If I crosslink a polymer film, does that increase the internal stress of the film? Intuitively I think it should for entropy reasons; chains with greater links are more restricted and have a smaller equilibrium radius.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on your thinking about this a bit, and be more specific? Under what condition do you think the stress would increase? What is the 'equilibrium radius' (I can think of several possible definitions). Why would this lead to greater stress?

Comment: My thinking is that, compared to an uncrosslinked Polymer chain, a cross-linked Polymer chain has restricted movement and therefore a lower equilibrium radius of gyration. That should mean that if the Polymer could freely move it would try to shrink

Comment: Are you talking about the stress in the material once an external load is applied?

Comment: @user190081, not specifically. I’m mainly thinking about a glassy Polymer below the glass transition temperature. If it becomes cross-linked, then maybe stress builds up in the Polymer which is then released when the temperature is increased sufficiently.